# Install winetricks application to ~/.wine prefix

Tags: wine

How can I tell winetricks to install an app to `~/.wine` instead of `~/.local/share/wineprefixes/<app-name>`?

I have already tried `WINEPREFIX=~/.wine winetricks <app-name>` without any success.

Answer (score 1):

`WINE_PREFIXES` can control the first part of the `WINEPREFIX` used... To keep it from creating subdirectories, use `WINETRICKS_OPT_SHAREDPREFIX=1`

So:

```
WINETRICKS_OPT_SHAREDPREFIX=1 winetricks bleh
```

Looks like that variable is also set by the `--no-isolate` option to winetricks.